# Auto format in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting

In sublime, you can just format (layout) any text/json/xml.

Is it possible to format a document (that might not be saved) automatically, without specify the type first?

Is there an add-in to detect file types and then layout can be applied?

**EDIT**

I would hope that VSCode could detect the file type, even if the document isn't saved.

e.g. if it starts with `{` probably json, if it starts with `<` probably XML?

(Note, it can layout unsaved documents, *if* you set the document type first)

I'm sure sublime can do this.

Comment: Not sure I understand your use case. In VSCode any document has a file type determined from file name or by using some heuristics (being *Plain Text* the default for new unsaved documents) and the *Format Document* command applies whatever formatter is configured for such type, if any. Can you please edit the question and elaborate on that?

Comment: @AlvaroGonzalez: Currently you have to have your document saved in order for Format Document to work properly, it wont work on unsaved documents, even if you choose the right language Mode!

Comment: @Breeze Weird. I cannot reproduce it. I've pasted some XML in a new tab and as long as I select *XML* with the *Change Language Mode* command I get proper formatting. Perhaps it depends on how the formatter is implemented?

Comment: @AlvaroGonzalez: yeah that may be it, it wont work on Python though! tested on 1.33.1 just now!